# How to capture wechat group incoming message and save it

Tags: wechat

need some advice from wechat experts.
How to get all incoming message from a specific wechat group and send it to server db.

Is there any available api or need to use xposed and hook the function of wechat.

Plz advice. Tq

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use wxBot: https://github.com/liuwons/wxBot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the specifics of wechat but if it is an Android app you can always intercept its text and images.

Check if the following suits your needs: [angel bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/aknahs/angel).

It is basically an Xposed module that intercepts TextViews and ImageViews in apps. It then sends them from the 3rd party apps to a standalone stub (running in the Xposed app itself). This stub sends them to a nodejs server that shows them in "real-time" in the browser.

Note that by default it is set to only intercept a few apps (whatsapp, facebook...) and while i made it modular, you will still have to build it yourself.